# update nested value of state using dynamic key

Tags: react-native, setstate

I wants to change grade object of state using dynamic key. Below is my code

```
state = {
            id1: {
                name: 'XYZ',
                grade: {
                    science: 'A',
                    maths: 'C',
                },
            },
            id2: {
                name: 'ABC',
                grade: {
                    science: 'A+',
                    maths: 'A+',
                },
            },
}
```

I tried couple of things but couldn't found successful result.

```
updateGrade(gradeObj, dyamicKey) { // dyamicKey will be id1, id2
    this.setState({
        [dyamicKey]: {
            ... dyamicKey.grade,
            grade: gradeObj,
        },
    });
}

updateGrade(gradeObj, dyamicKey) { // dyamicKey will be id1, id2
    this.setState({
        [dyamicKey[grade]]: gradeObj,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  [dyamicKey]: {
    ...prevState[dyamicKey],
    grade: gradeObj,
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

**FYI: this topic was extensively cover [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react), and even is recommended not to use nested states, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react#51136076)**.

As an extra comment to the first answer and for the ones to come, if you have two or more nested values in your state and you want to update a single nested value, you could do the following:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  [dynamicKey]: {
  ...prevState[dynamicKey],
  grade: { 
    ...prevState[dynamicKey].grade,
    science: "Z"
  },
}));
```

Or, if the dynamic key is related to a specific attribute:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  id1: {
  ...prevState.id1,
  grade: { 
    ...prevState.id1.grade,
    [dynamicKey]: "Z"
  },
}));
```

One or more dynamic keys can be used and the spread operator can be used for each nested level (although the code will start to look ugly/dirty with this approach).